# Redirect to page but keep original URL using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^test\.localhost/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test\.localhost/err.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

This works. When I type test.localhost/qwieoqjdoiqwje it redirects me to:

test.localhost/err.php/qwieoqjdoiqwje

But I want to redirect me to redirect me to test.localhost/qwieoqjdoiqwje and also load err.php . Is this possible via htaccess? Thanks1

Comment: What is full URL you entered? Is `/test.localhost/` a foder?

Comment: you want to be redirected to test.localhost/qwieoqjdoiqwje and also load err.php? i'm not clear.

Comment: FYI, you should acknowledge and/or accept answers that work for you so that people will continue to provide support to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by redirecting all requests to one file with .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  # Block access to hidden files
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  # Redirect requests that are not files or directories to index.php.
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then in your index.php use the path to execute whatever function you want.

```
  if ($path == 'error' || $path == 'hello/world')
  {
     myerrorfunction();
  }
```

This is of course a very simple solution. You would probably want to create an array that maps a path to a funciton. this is how most cms systems acomplish this task.